# pygame.transform.scale not working on a font surface

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a function in a pygame program for python 3. The function basically makes the multiple-line process of blitting words onto the screen simpler by making it one function, `MakeWord()`. It has some parameters to adjust size, font, position, etc. Instead of making the font based on normal font sizes, I wanted it based on pixel sizes so I did `pygame.transfom.flip()` on a font surface and it did not work. Can someone find the problem please?

```
def MakeWord(Phrase, Font, Color, Pos, Size):
    FontType = pygame.font.SysFont(Font, 400) #400 because the size will be changed anyways
    FontSurf = FontType.render(Phrase, True, Color)
    pygame.transform.scale(FontSurf, Size) #Does not work
    FontRect = FontSurf.get_rect()
    FontRect.topleft = Pos
    Display.blit(FontSurf, FontRect)
    return FontRect #For FontRect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos) used later
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.transform.scale`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) returns a new Surface object. Try to assign it to `FontSurf`:

```
FontSurf = pygame.transform.scale(FontSurf, Size)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, This works. I thought it changes the first surface.